# How to change Relay Environment with in React-Native app?

Tags: relayjs

I've been working with this issue of trying to set the authorization header in the relay environment after the user signs-in. I've tried this suggestion [React relay injectNetworkLayer is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45972661/react-relay-injectnetworklayer-is-not-a-function) I have tried using a class that wraps the environment has a token property that when updated creates the Authorization header and places the token into it. This also threw an error. There has to be a way to do this but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

How about storing the token in AsyncStorage when you log in, then in your fetch function, you try to read the token form AsyncStorage, and add it as a header if it is not null.